# How to make a standalone mac app using qtcreator

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt-creator

I have build an app using C++ and Qt on QtCreator. The result is a .app file.

Now, when I am running it from the Qt Creator it is running fine. 
But when I am running it on a different machine (with no Qt installed) it is not running.

[image: error screen dump]
I have figured out the reason is because my .app file is not deployed properly (as there is no framework folder added in the .app)

But I am now having trouble solving it. I am following this [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-mac.html) but not getting anywhere as it for console purely.

Is there a way I can fix it using Qt Creator?

Answer (score 1):

A Qt application relies upon Qt's libraries, which must be shipped with the application, inside the built application bundle. The steps for deploying a Qt application for OS X are detailed in the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/macosx-deployment.html).

If you're not using any other libraries, besides those of Qt, you just need to run the tool **macdeployqt**, which is part of the Qt installation, in the bin directory. You can set this up to run as a build step in Qt Creator, but I suggest only doing it before you actually deploy the final bundle to another machine.

Calling macdeployqt will copy the necessary Qt frameworks into the bundle and setup the paths to the frameworks so that the binary in the bundle knows where to find them.

If you use any other frameworks or libraries, you need to copy those yourself and set the references to them using [install_name_tool](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/install_name_tool/)